# How to install angular-mocks via bower.json?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, bash, angular-mock

Why can't I install `angular-mocks` via `bower.json`?

```
{
  "name": "boilerplate",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "latest",
    "angular-route": "latest"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "latest"
    }
}
```

It freezes my Git Bash each time when I run `bower install`.

I only can install `angular-mocks` via `npm` - why?

Comment: Works for me. `bower -v -> 1.3.12`

Comment: Did you try with native terminal instead? What happens when Git Bash freezes?

Comment: nothing happened when it freezes...

Comment: i'm on `bower -v -> 1.3.12` as well...